# Most like / Like most

Tags: best-most

My question has to do with the placement of "most" before or after the verb.  Is the following sentence correct/acceptable?

**I most like apples.**

Alternatives: 
I like most apples. 
I like apples most.

Answer (score 4):

Different meanings.

> I most like apples.

This feels a little awkward, but means "I like apples more than anything else".

> I like most apples.

This is normal, and means "I like the majority of apples" (in practice, it probably means "I like the majority of kinds of apple").

> I like apples most.

is a more normal way of saying your first example. Even more colloquially "I like apples most of all."

Comment: excellent sir.Is it an example of "inversion". what about " I like apples the most'.

Comment: Yes, that would be an alternative to _I like apples most_. It is not what grammarians usually call inversion, which involves a verb and its subject. It is more about the placement of adverbs: they often have several possible sites, some of them with very different meanings.

Answer (score -1):

Your phrases are all correct, but have different meanings. 'I most like apples' has a rather antiquated feel to it.
Perhaps another form of words would suit better. 
I prefer apples. Of all fruits, I prefer apples. Of all fruits, I most like apples.

Answer (score -1):

Agreed with Colin that *I most like apples* is awkward. I can think of the following variations, each with a different meaning:

> I like most apples.

Meaning that there are some apples I do not like.

> I like apples most.

Meaning that there are other fruits I like, but not as much as I like apples.

> I mostly like apples.

Meaning that most of the time I like apples, but sometimes I don't; or, that I only somewhat dislike apples.

> I am most like apples.

Meaning that of all the things I could be compared with, apples are the closest thing that I am like. :)